# how to get data from child node in firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nosql

my database structure is

```
appname:
        Tasks:
             childbyautoid1:
                            "name": "myname"
                            "age": "18"
             childbyautoid2:
                            "name": "yourname"
                            "age": "20"
```

I want to know how to get all data that is name and age of all the child node as I don't know the `childbyautoid`

I am writing

```
Database.database().reference().child("Tasks").observe(.childAdded){ (dss) in 
if let value = dss.value  as? [String: AnyObject]{ 

    let name = value["name"] as? String
    let age = value["age"] as? String
    print(name)
    print(age)

}
```

Comment: try `as? [[String: Any]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through every child like this:

```
    // Create a reference to the database path
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Tasks")

    // You can keep your database synced
    ref.keepSynced(true)

    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    // Checking if the reference has some values
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

        // Go through every child
        for data in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if let data = data.value as? [String: Any] {

                // Retrieve the data per child

                // Example
                let name = data["name"] as? String
                let age = data["age"] as? String

                // Print the values for each child or do whatever you want
                print("Name: \(name)\nAge: \(age)")
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[String: Any]]` instead of `[String: Any]` then loop inside of it for each `Dictionary` and map out result, should be something like this.

```
if let value = dss.value  as? [[String: Any]]{
    for val in value {
        let name = val["name"] as? String
        let age = val["age"] as? String
        print(name)
        print(age)
    }
```